# Why is propanoic acid often added to the diet of C. elegans?

Tags: molecular-biology

And what are its effects on C. elegans?

The paper is  [**Burnett C, Valentini S, Cabreiro F, Goss M, Somogyvári M, Piper MD, Hoddinott M, Sutphin GL, Leko V, McElwee JJ, et al.**. 2011. Absence of effects of Sir2 overexpression on lifespan in C. elegans and Drosophila. Nature 477: 482–5.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nature10296)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Propanoic acid is toxic against many types of mold, fungi and bacteria ([wiki](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0031942204002973)), but same time has almost no effect to C. elegans ("fivefold less", [reference](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0031942204002973)). This is why propanoic acids and (more commmon) its salts are used as conservants for C.elegans cultures (as well as for other animals, like Drosophila).

Comment: Another anti-fungal compound we use in our fly lab is methylparaben.

Comment: We use nystatin. I don't think the use of propanoic acid with C elegans is that common. Fly people use it a lot.